Can a Linux Kernel Module read safely a user space command (i.e. user buffer)?
Can a Linux Kernel Module read safely a user space command (i.e. user buffer)?
I know kernel and user space are different: user memory can not be executed from kernel space and vice-versa.
I wrote some simple LKM where commands coming from user space where simple: there, you can just copy the user buffer (command) to a kernel buffer using copy_from_user.
Now I have a more complex LKM, and, I wonder if I can parse the user buffer (i.e. just reading it - not executing it), check if the command is valid, and then only copy the user buffer (command) to a kernel buffer using copy_from_user (once you know the command is valid).
Is it OK to read user buffer from kernel space?

You would need to either copy it to kernel space (not necessarily all at once), or temporarily pin the user space memory to kernel address space, before you can parse it.

While the command is in the user-space memory, the user can change it at any time. E.g. Just after your driver checks the correctness but before copy_from_user is executed. That is, it is usually has no sense to check the user input without preliminary copy it into the kernel space.

OK, so the answer is no: first, copy from user to kernel space, then handle valid/invalid cases in kernel space
